# Slider scrolls based on the slider item class name

Tags: jquery, slick.js

How its should be,
[image]
Gray color is the screen

When I hit next the 1st item on the category(red) should be the 1st position on the slider,
Now its r1, then I hit next again its y1, then p1, etc...

The same case happen when I hit prev

Slider : Slick slider

I believe a few lines jQuery will helps me, but I am poor in jQuery.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not something that's built in to Slick.js or simple to add. You could mark the first slide of each group, determine its slide index, and then add an event to your arrows which calls the `slickGoTo()` method to jump to that slide index.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post your HTML code structure I'm just basing my answer on the slick slider documentation.

Here's what they have:

```
$('.multiple-items').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 5
});
```

Here's the link to the docs: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: But the numbers are not constant, each category have different numbers of items
Example: 5 red blocks, 3 yellows, 4 pinks, etc